# Rotation Physics On A Cube

Tags: rotation, physics, game-physics

This problem has been bugging me for a while, without being language specific can anyone tell me how I could calculate the rotation of say, a cube, when it collides and a force is put upon it?  I have searched through my fathers engineering book but I'm just not sure how to ask the question shortly.  I know I can not explain this well but I'll do my best:

Imagine you have a cube fallin toward a ledge, the cube's center falls over the edge so the object will fall

```
                                               Rotation
                  --------   ||  Gravity      _->    __       ||  Gravity
                  |      |   ||              /      /  ---    ||
                  |      |   \/             /      /      --  \/
                  --------                  |     /__       /
___________________                  ______________  ---   /
                   |                               |    --/
```

So does anyone know where I could go to read more about this or things like it?  And especially how to apply this to a program with several different shapes (i.e. rectangles, circles, Irregular shapes)  The best idea I have is that it has something to do with the center of mass and the vector force, but I'm lost from there.  Any Ideas?

Comment: this isn't programming (yet). it's basic physics.

Comment: perhaps a video game perspective: http://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-i-an-introduction-to-rigid-body-dynamics

Comment: Have you studied introductory Physics? I don't think you have much hope of getting this to work without that background knowledge.

Comment: See the cube as eight point-masses which effect each other with strong bonds. This way you dont even need to write anything about rotation.